# Cannot read properties of undefined passing error when passing observable object NgModel

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, http, observable

I am trying to pass an object to NgModel in my angular template but I am recieving the error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'boxName')" In my .ts file when I was initializing my custom box: Box variable it was forcing me to initialize it to undefined so box : Box = | undefined I went into my tsconfig.json and switched my strictPropertyIntialization to false. So I no longer have to initialize the variable to undefined. I am using NgPrime and was passing the box object being used to an editBox function (https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaW9Y.jpg)

This is being passed to this function in my .ts file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdyH.jpg)

when the editbutton is clicked I log the "box" being passed to the function and it has all the correct fields and info in json format. But as you can see in the console I am getting an error.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IE8Q.jpg)

Guessing it has something to do with having to subscribe to the observable it is returning but since I am passing the box object to the template as an ngmodel I thought I would be fine. In this image you can see where it occurs at line 65 where i set my ngmodel to box.boxName (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw12g.jpg)

If someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated, also for context here is my service that I access when calling editBox(). Also for reference "Box" is an interface setup in another file.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBKfv.jpg)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0):

In some stage your box is not yet be initial or equal to undefined, so you need optional operator (`?`) to prevent that error, eg. `[(ngModel)]="box?.boxName"`

**Alternative solution.**

In the line `<div class="formgrid grid">`, You can add condition to prevent template to use `box` object

```
<div class="formgrid grid" *ngIf="box">
```

Comment: In my .ts file I have "box : Box;" so when I add the question mark it underlines it with red and says   The left side of this optional chain operation does not include 'null' or 'undefined' in its type, therefore the '?.' operator can be replaced with the '.' operator.ngtsc(-998107)

Comment: I update my answer, wish it could help.